# How to navigate multiple pages on single window (via frame) WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a project in which I have a requirement to show multiple pages in a single window now my question is I have a component inside a frame (page) and in any event of it I want the user to navigate to a different page (in some scenario I want to change one page or multiple) please suggest me a better way of it.

This is my folder structure
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp4Sx.png)

This is  my main Window
[Main Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxpHc.png)

This is my ViewModel
[View Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g6XB.png)

Property is Changing From the command but I am not seeing any changes to UI
[Property Reflected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHssb.png)

Here is my Source Code

Answer (score 0):

You could create `ViewModel` for each page you want to display and make them inherit from the same class

```
public class Page1 : PageViewModel
public class Page2 : PageViewModel
```

In the `MainViewModel` you can create a list of pages you want to display and currently displayed page

```
public PageViewModel CurrentPage
public List<PageViewModel> AllPages
```

And now if your MainWindow have access to those fields you can bind the page and display it

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

I am not sure if you can put a `Frame` into `ContentPresenter`, you could try changing Frame to `UserControl`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I require to show 2 Pages at a time

Comment: You could create two variables CurrentPage1, CurrentPage2, and display them in two separate ContentPresenters in your MainView. Then you need an event to change currently displayed pages. You could create "next" buttons that would execute a function CurrentPage = AllPages.ElementAt(index++) in your view model

Comment: I am not able to perform that can you please look into solution transfernow.net/ddl/stackoverflowsolution  Thanks in advance.